# Slow performance using oracle xmltable function from Visual Studio application

Tags: c#, sql, xml, oracle, visual-studio

I have a table (MyTable) with different fields and one of them is an xml structure. Each structure contains one or more object of what we can call Object_1, i.e. every row in the table has a field that has one or more of Object_1.

Therefore I extract fields from each Object_1 like:

```
select m.Field_1, m.Field_2, x.Object_1_Field_1, x.Object_1_Field_2
from MyTable m,
xmltable( xmlnamespaces(some_namespace), 
         '/Document' passing xmltype(m.Field_Object_1), 
         Object_1_Field_1 as varchar2(35) path 'Object_1_Field_1',
         Object_1_Field_2 as varchar2(35) path 'Object_1_Field_2'
        ) x
Where...
```

This takes around 20 seconds to run in SQL Developer, but when I do it from my Visual Studio Application, it takes like 5 minutes.
The reason is clearly that some of the Field_Object_1 fields from MyTable have 50-100 Object_1's. When I remove these, the run time in SQL Developer and the Visual Studio application is somewhat comparable.

Would anyone know how I can avoid this? It is some memory issue I guess?

Please let me know if I should provide more info or if anything is unclear.

Thanks in advance - much appreciated.

Kind Regards
Martin

Comment: Is there a way you can re-evaluate the query? - that is, check the conditions and rewrite the query if needed. I don't really have experience on this, but check the SQL Developer Execution Plan of the query.

Comment: Hi Marco, the thing is that the performance in SQL Developer is quite good, but it is really bad when using the Visual Studio Application that is running the exact same query.

Comment: It is the driver that is used in Net (SQLClient).  Rather than use SQLClient you can use a different driver.  See connectionstrings.com.  You can also use the powershell interface in c# which uses the same interface as sqlcmd.exe.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16.  Or you can run sqlcmd.exe from c# as a process.

Comment: Thanks :) I am not very familiar with powershell, but I have tried using System.Management.Automation nuget package and specifying 'PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand($"sqlcmd -d {database} -Q {query} -U {username} -P {password}");' but it doesn't work and I am pretty sure the -d parameter is incorrect, i.e. in lack of a better idea I just used the DataSource parameter from my former connection string '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = <host>)(PORT = <port>)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = <service_name>) ) )'. Any suggestions?